# Rounding to 2 Decimal in Perl

Tags: perl, rounding

**Symptom**
My below function return wrong rounding 0.57 instead 0.58

**Perl Source**

```
#Live Demo 
#!/usr/bin/perl

#### INPUT PARAMETERS
$rate=0.505;
$spread=0.07;
$precision=2;

#### DEBUG
print " Debug Session \n";
$rate1 = (10**$precision)*($rate+$spread);
print " 001  Rate1 is $rate1\n";
$rate2 = ((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5;
print " 002  Rate2 is $rate2\n";
$rate3 = int (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5);
print " 003  Rate3 is $rate3\n";
$rate4 = int (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5)/(10**$precision);
print " 004  Rate4 is $rate4\n";
#### PRODUCTION
print " Production Session \n";
$rate = int (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5)/(10**$precision);
print " Production  Rate_production is $rate\n";
```

Comment: `$rate2` is not exactly equal to 58 it is 57.9999999999999929 that is why the `int()` rounds down to 57 instead of keeping 58

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation for the `int` functions of Perl (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/int.html)

> Returns the integer portion of EXPR. If EXPR is omitted, uses $_ . You should not use this function for rounding: one because it truncates towards 0 , and two because machine representations of floating-point numbers can sometimes produce counterintuitive results. For example, int(-6.725/0.025) produces -268 rather than the correct -269; that's because it's really more like -268.99999999999994315658 instead. Usually, the sprintf, printf, or the POSIX::floor and POSIX::ceil functions will serve you better than will int.

**Updated to use sprintf:**

```
#Live Demo 
#!/usr/bin/perl

#### INPUT PARAMETERS
$rate=0.505;
$spread=0.07;
$precision=2;

#### DEBUG
print " Debug Session \n";
$rate1 = (10**$precision)*($rate+$spread);
print " 001  Rate1 is $rate1\n";
$rate2 = ((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5;
print " 002  Rate2 is $rate2\n";
$rate3 = sprintf ("%.2f", (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5));
print " 003  Rate3 is $rate3\n";
$rate4 = sprintf ("%.2f", (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5))/(10**$precision);
print " 004  Rate4 is $rate4\n";
#### PRODUCTION
print " Production Session \n";
$rate = sprintf ("%.2f", (((10**$precision)*($rate+$spread))+0.5))/(10**$precision);
print " Production  Rate_production is $rate\n";
```

Comment: The `10**$precision` stuff is superfluous if you are already rounding with `sprintf`.  `$rate=sprintf("%.2f",$rate+$spread)` is sufficient (and doesn't confuse things with the `$err` term)